# Python variable interchange not working properly?

Tags: python, arrays, list, sorting, python-3.x

i worte a code to reverse the elements of a list. here, i apply the algorithm that i run a loop form 0 to length of string, and interchange values as I go. i basically do a switch between two variables at a time using a third temp variable:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
g = len(l) - 1
for i in range (0, len(l)):
    m = l[i]
    l[i] = l[g]
    l[g] = m
    g -= 1
print(l)
```

however, l prints as the original list. logically i am failing to see any flaws in the code. everything has been exchanged properly as far as i can see.

Comment: try: for i in range (0, len(l) / 2):

Comment: @PasteBT -- I'd suggest integer division:  `len(l) // 2`

Comment: @mgilson: you mean "5 / 2 != 5 // 2" ?

Comment: @PasteBT Correct.  That statement is `False` on python2.x (they're the same unless future_division is enabled), but it's `True` on python3.x (they're different)

Comment: @mgilson. Thanks, I am not using python 3 yet.

Comment: @PasteBT -- A lot of people aren't (I still don't use it regularly).  But I python3.x is here and it's going to be here longer than python2.x, so we might as well start getting used to it :)

Comment: @mgilson, yes, you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the logic is that you're looping over the entire list.  Since you swap 2 elements at each turn of the loop, you only need to iterate over half the list to swap all the values.

In other words, when you iterate over the first half of the list indices, you reverse it.  Then, when you iterate over the second half of the indices, *you reverse it back*.

---

As a side note, a really cool way to swap values in python is:

```
a, b = b, a
```

Or in your case:

```
l[i], l[g] = l[g], l[i]
```

Comment: Talking of cool ways, `l[::-1]` will do what OP wants in one line :P

Comment: got it. thanks, but what will i do if the number of elements in list are odd? do i give a special condition?

Comment: @Thrustmaster -- sure... or `l.reverse()` :)

Comment: @amin -- I'm sure you can play around with it an figure it out ;-).  I haven't thought it through too well, but I don't think you need a special condition.  Just use integer division because the middle element doesn't *need* to be swapped with anything.

Comment: @mgilson alrite man, thanks. i'll mark ur answer right in a bit

Answer (score 0):

```
#loop time should be len(1)/2

l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
g = len(l) - 1
for i in range (0, len(l)/2):
    m = l[i]
    l[i] = l[g]
    l[g] = m
    g -= 1
print(l)
```